# Insert variable into imported string

Tags: javascript

I am trying to define constants in one file and use them in another.

I know this wont work but what is the correct way to do this?

```
// const.js
export const GREETING = `Hello, ${name}`;

// displayGreeting.js
import { GREETING } from './const';
def displayGreeting(name) {
  return GREETING
}

>>> displayGreeting('barry')
>>> Hello, barry
```

Comment: You could create `const GREETING = name => \`Hello, ${name}\`;` and then use `GREETING(name)` inside `displayGreeting`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of exporting a string (defined with a template literal), export a *function* which takes a parameter, which is then interpolated into a returned template literal:

```
export const makeGreeting = name => `Hello, ${name}`;
```

and

```
import { makeGreeting } from './const';
makeGreeting('barry');
```

Also, `def displayGreeting(name) {` is not valid Javascript - declare functions with `function`, or `() =>`, or something of the sort.

Answer (score -1):

```
// const.js - exports a function
export const greeting = name => `Hello, ${name}`;

// index.js
import { greeting } from "./const";
const greetBarry = GREETING("barry");
console.log(greetBarry);

//Hello, barry
```

[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/embed/blazing-shadow-ocksb)